# It it possible to stop loading debug symbols for ASP.NET view pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging

Loading pages in debug mode seems to be really slow. I am suspecting that it comes from loading the Debug symbols. I barely have any C# code in my views (I just bind one big JSON object and than use knockout.js for my templating)

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\25240b3c\d5bf21f1\App_Web_1mszksk3.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\25240b3c\d5bf21f1\App_Web_njuv3hls.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Dirk\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\25240b3c\d5bf21f1\App_Web__poolprofile.cshtml.639c3968.tlc_zku4.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Is it possible to stop loading Symbols for my views - while keeping full debug support for my Controllers, Models and other Application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio menu choose Debug->Option and Settings then in left pane choose Symbols.
Then select "only specified modules"  and choose libraries you need.